# Parallel operations in sql server running "sequentially "

Tags: sql-server, database, parallel-processing

There are n databases in our windows application where the schema is same. 
We have a requirement where we need to export the databases as mirrors but only a subset of data should be copied.

For this we are following

1. Create a new empty DB.
2. Run a script which inserts selected data into the DB based on a key.
3. After insert we detach the DB.
4. steps 1,2,3 are run for each database which needs to be shipped.

Inserts we are running in batches. Our plan is to run parallel for each database which needs to be exported.

When we run for large data it takes 6 minutes for a database.

And if I run the same script for 5 different databases in 5 different sessions simultaneously. The last script finishes running by 30-32 minutes. Which means even though they are running parallel time taken is same as sequential.

We disabled all indexes and at end we are rebuilding them
The database is supposed to be in simple logging mode we are turning them to bulk logging mode and turning back to simple logging.
We tried using MAXDOP(0) and (1) -- No change
NO LOCK Hint is being used in all select queries.

I want to understand what should I do to get best performance, because they are 5 different databases being copied to 5 new databases where all operations are supposed to be independent.

Comment: Throughput will be ultimately limited by hardware so running more tasks in parallel won't help once you reach a bottleneck, especially CPU or storage. Monitor CPU and disk during execution to see if you are at or near capacity.